# Asp.net on Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit

I recently upgraded my web server to Windows 2003 R2 Enterprise 64 Bit. Now my website developed using Asp.net is not able to load reports developed using Crystal reports. The reason is Crystal reports dll are unable to load as they are 32 bit. 
To solve the above issue, I forced the aspnet_compiler.exe to compile in X86 mode. This was achieved by adding the following element in web.config

```
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
                type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                warningLevel="4"
              compilerOptions="/platform:x86">
```

After adding this, I compiled and deployed again. But the site stopped working. It started throwing exception which stopped application pool.

It will be great help if somebody can find a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the 64 bit installer for the crystal runtime.

Got it, [here](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100009351332008E/CRBasicVS2008_redist_x64.zip).